# Import sql file from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to upload **.sql** file to a localhost server using **Java**. The problem is that I do not load the **.sql** but it does show me the message "Backup OK!".

**Utilities**: Windows 10, Netbeans 8.2, JDK 1.8, Xampp/phpmyadmin

**Classes / Methods:**

```
public class Conexiones {
    static String bbdd = "agenda";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    static Connection c = null;

    public static String getUsuario() {
       return usuario;
    }

    public static String getPassword() {
       return password;
    }

    public static String getBBDD() {
       return bbdd;
    }

    public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
            return c;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace(), "Admin", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed!", "Admin", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**JFileChooser:**

```
private void button_seleccionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    JFileChooser file= new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter extension = new FileNameExtensionFilter("SQL", "sql");
    file.setFileFilter(extension);
    int se = file.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(se == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        String ruta = archivo.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        textfield_ubicacion.setText(ruta);
    }
}
```

**ActionPerformed (button) - Import .SQL:**

```
private void button_cargarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String ruta = textfield_ubicacion.getText();
    String backup = "";
    if(ruta.trim().length()!=0){
        try{
            backup = "mysqldump -u"+Conexiones.getUsuario()+" -p"+Conexiones.getPassword()+" "+Conexiones.getBBDD()+" < "+ruta+"";
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            r.exec(backup);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup OK!");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Run program:**

1. I access `JFileChooser` -> OK
2. I select the `SQL` file and put it in the `textfield_ubicacion`
   -> OK
3. Pulse the `button` shows me "Backup OK!" but does not load it. In
   `phpmyadmin` BBDDs it doesn't appear to me. (ERROR here).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232406/discussion-on-question-by-srcantabri-import-sql-file-from-java).

Answer (score 0):

In the **CMD** command console I use the command:

```
mysql -u root -p < C:\Users\omaza\OneDrive\Desktop\bbddclientes.sql
```

[image]

Inside the **.sql** file, there are the database creation lines:

```
CREATE DATABASE agenda;
USE agenda;
```

In Java, the sign `<` is not recognized. So I had to try another restore method:

```
private void button_cargarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String ruta = textfield_ubicacion.getText();
    String[] restoreCmd = new String[]{"mysql ", "--user=" + Conexiones.getUsuario(), "--password=" + Conexiones.getPassword(), "-e", "source " + ruta};
    try {
        Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(restoreCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup OK!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed.");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```